# javax.sound.midi.Sequencer concurrency

Tags: java, wav, midi

I'm developing a genetic algorithm using the java watchmaker framework, which is concurrent. I need to create a wav file using the  javax.sound.midi.Sequencer and a MIDI secuence. My problem is that I cannot instanciate two concurrent secuencers.... it is throwing the following error:

```
javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getDefaultDeviceWrapper(MidiSystem.java:1112)
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequencer(MidiSystem.java:439)
    at org.jfugue.Player.getSequencerConnectedToSynthesizer(Player.java:478)
    at frerejacques.Midi2WavRenderer.createWavFile(Midi2WavRenderer.java:136)
    at frerejacques.FrereJacques.generateSong(FrereJacques.java:62)
    at frerejacques.FrereJacques$2.run(FrereJacques.java:98)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MidiDevice Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth not supported by this provider.
    at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractMidiDeviceProvider.getDevice(AbstractMidiDeviceProvider.java:147)
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getFirstDevice(MidiSystem.java:1351)
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getFirstDevice(MidiSystem.java:1406)
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getFirstDevice(MidiSystem.java:1373)
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getDefaultDevice(MidiSystem.java:1160)
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getDefaultDeviceWrapper(MidiSystem.java:1110)
    ... 5 more
```

Any ideas on how to use two diferent secuencers at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Java (and Windows) consider synthesizers as hardware devices, so it is not possible to open them multiple times.

You have to share a single device (which would result in a single output), or use [some software synthesizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143566/software-synth-library-for-java) that works inpependently from devices.